# MySQL request from multiple tables slow because of WHERE filters

Tags: mysql, request, performance

I am using request to select data from 10 tables and at the end i have WHERE and 2 conditions
first one is simple but with second one it slows down dramatically even when there is no results returned.

```
AND (eligible_users.id IS NULL OR 
((eligible_users.program = 3 AND eligible_users.status = 0) 
OR eligible_users.status = 35))
```

When i remove it, page loads much fast, is there some way to make it faster but still keep this filter because i need it.

Comment: Have you run an EXPLAIN on the query? What does it say?

Comment: Perhaps you need an index on your "status" column. You can add it like this: `CREATE INDEX status_index ON eligible_users (status);`

Comment: Also, I second what @jasonbar said. The output of EXPLAIN will, well, explain how your query is evaluated. And it will tell you if you are missing indexes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 OR statements in the query, try splitting them into 1 or more unions like so:

```
select ...
where ... 
eligible_users.id IS NULL 
UNION
select ...
where ...
(eligible_users.program = 3 AND eligible_users.status = 0) 
OR eligible_users.status = 35
```

Comment: Then i cannot use order by it does not work same as if it was one query

Comment: @JohnU43 Yes you can: `select * from (select ... union select ...) t order by t.your_column`

Answer (score 0):

Adding two indexes, one for program and one for status would probably speed things up nicely.

Comment: you mean indexes that in table itself, even though they are not used in request

Comment: @JohnU43 Yes, indexes on the table, for those specific fields. Indexes should help the database evaluate your where clause faster.